# Nested JSON object in PLSQL

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

How can I write plsql code for below example

```
"charts":
    [
        {
            "name":"CHART_1",
            "type":"bar",
            "data":
            [
                {
                  "id": 0,
                  "series": "Initial",
                  "group": "Deals",
                  "value":42
                },
                {
                  "id": 1,
                  "series": "Qualification",
                  "group": "Deals",
                  "value":55
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried to solve the problem so far, and express explicitly what you got as input.

Comment: Have you googled "oracle pl/sql json" ? Many people a lot smarter than us have written blogs about this subject with excellent examples. Do that, give it a try, learn what the possibilities are, maybe even read the official documentation and if you get stuck, post it on stack overflow.

Comment: What code you want to write ? It's more of a open question what do do ?but I am pretty sure with suggestion from @Koen Lostrie.  Give it a try and it's easy with the JSON what you have, believe me.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare
  vjson    pljson;
  vjinner  pljson;
  vjinner1 pljson;
  vjinner2 pljson;
  vjlist   pljson_list := pljson_list();
begin

  vjinner := pljson();
  vjinner.put('id', 0);
  vjinner.put('series', 1);
  vjinner.put('group', 2);
  vjinner.put('value', 3);

  vjlist.append(vjinner);

  vjinner1 := pljson();
  vjinner1.put('id', 0);
  vjinner1.put('series', 1);
  vjinner1.put('group', 2);
  vjinner1.put('value', 3);

  vjlist.append(vjinner1);

  vjinner2 := pljson();
  vjinner2.put('name', 'chart_1');
  vjinner2.put('type', 'bar');
  vjinner2.put('data', vjlist);

  vjson := pljson();

  vjson.put('charts', vjinner2);

  dbms_output.put_line(pljson_printer.pretty_print(obj => vjson, spaces => true));

end;
```

result:

```
{   "charts" : {
    "name" : "chart_1",
    "type" : "bar",
    "data" : [{
      "id" : 0,
      "series" : 1,
      "group" : 2,
      "value" : 3
    }, {
      "id" : 0,
      "series" : 1,
      "group" : 2,
      "value" : 3
    }]   } }
```

before install this:
https://github.com/pljson/pljson
and try.